# Rails Association: 2 occurrences of same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have a `Consultation` model that has a `post_consultant` and a `consultant`.  Both `post_consultant` and `consultant` are references to the `Employee` model.  So you could say:

**Model**

```
Class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :employee # for consultant
    has_one :employee # for post_consultant
end
```

**Migration**

```
create_table "consultations", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.boolean "showed_up"
  t.boolean "signed_up"
  t.integer "client_id"
  t.integer "consultant_id"
  t.integer "post_consultant_id"
end
```

**How am I supposed to write that?**

---

**Correct Model:**

```
class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :consultant, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "consultant_id"
    belongs_to :post_consultant, class_name: "Employee", foreign_key: "post_consultant_id"
end
```

Comment: post_consultant and consultant is a model?

Comment: which foreign key for post_consultant and consultant?

Comment: only employee is a model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :consultant, :class_name => "Employee", :foreign_key=> "consultant_id", dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :post_consultant, :class_name=>"Employee", :foreign_key=> "post_consultant_id", dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: its just strange, when I try: `c = Consultation.new`.  `e = Employee.first`.  And then attempt  `c.consultant = e` I see the following error: `ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError: can't write unknown attribute 'consultant_id'`

Comment: Please verify whether u have an field called consultant_id and post_consultant_id column in the table  consultations in schema

Comment: I have both in the consultation table

Comment: @Jeremy Thomas,  then we need to change association, it should be belongs_to

Comment: ughhh duhh!  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can define multiple relation referring to same model.

```
Class Consultation < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :consultant, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: :consultant_id
    has_one :post_consultant, class_name: 'Employee', foreign_key: :post_consultant_id
end
```

**Note**: mention whichever foreign key you are using for each association using syntax above.

Comment: please see comment on response above